# Angular.JS: why can't the inputs be edited?

Tags: angularjs

This is a strange problem. The code is simple:

HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
  </ul>
</body>
```

Angular code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
});
```

The live demo url is: http://plnkr.co/edit/2QFgRooeFUTgJOo223k9?p=preview

I do not understand why the input controls can not be edited, I can't type new characters or delete characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common issue due to scope inheritance . Each of your `names` is a primitive so `ng-repeat` makes it's own scope item that is not connected to original, however if each `names` is an object `ng-repeat` scope item will be a reference to original object

```
 [{name:"aaa"},{name:"bbb"},{name:"ccc"}];
```

Always use a `dot` in `ng-model` is a helpful rule of thumb

```
<div ng-repeat="item in names">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.name"/>
    </div>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bbzuZFBLyRAIoaMnZMmf?p=preview)

Read this article on angular github wiki for detailed explanaton:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance

Answer (score 3):

Angular 'fixed' this in 1.1 with the track by $index. No need to change your model.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in names track by $index">
    <input type="text" ng-model="names[$index]" />
</div>
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nMPsPmn4KcAonuG3hAkx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you should also be careful of typos, that angular will not warn you about:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in names track by $index" ng=if="names[$index] = 'John'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="names[$index]" />
</div>
```

Note the single equals in the ng-if, that will not cause a warning or error, but the text will also be read only. Quite a hard one to spot if you are reading quickly.

It of course should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in names track by $index" ng-if="names[$index] == 'John'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="names[$index]" />
</div>
```