# ng-model as a variable in a bidimensional array

Tags: angularjs

```
  <p ng-repeat="row in matrix">
    <span ng-repeat="column in row">
      <input type="text" style="width: 20px; text-align: center;" ng-model="column" ng-change="{{column = }}">
    </span>
  </p>
```

And on my controller:

```
$scope.matrix = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]];
```

I have little piece of code and I want that little text input box to be associated with `matrix[i][u]`. I know I can use `ng-model=` to make the text box be associated with a certain variable.

However, I want it to go both ways - changing the variable will change the text box value and changing the text box value will change the variable. However, when I have `ng-model` on an input text box I can't seem to edit its value, as it'll always "reset" to its default.

I know I can use `ng-change` but I made the middle line this:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 20px; text-align: center;" ng-model="column" ng-change="update">
```

And it didn't work to call the $scope.update() function. I also still can't edit the text box value.

tl;dr: How can I have a text box with an `ng-model` and allow editing it to edit both the text box value and the variable on ng-model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720334/angular-js-why-cant-the-inputs-be-edited I now found that but according to that mine should be working too.

Comment: I don't see anything in that question/answer which indicates that you solution should be working. The problem here is that each ``ng-repeat`` creates a child scope and if you end up at the "scalar" level of variables this will create variables disconnected from their parent.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720334/angular-js-why-cant-the-inputs-be-edited

Comment: Again: What is written and shown there does not apply here. That question does not show that your code should work.

Comment: The reason that one works is because those are objects and you've just got ints. If you had actual objects, this would work without $index or anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="matrix[$index][$parent.$index]" style="width: 20px; text-align: center;" />
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/hcLVE/

It is not very elegant , but it is working..

Comment: I would suspect that ``row[$index]`` would work as well. Also: Aren't your two indices in the wrong order? The latter index is the "inner" one, so shouldn't it be ``matrix[$parent.$index][$index]``?

Comment: No, you actually proofed my point. The first argument ``[0]`` clearly references the outer array and the second argument ``[2]`` references the inner one. Therefore the result is 2. So it is ``[outer][inner]`` and therefore would need to be ``[$parent.$index][$index]`` because the parent index is the outer array here.

Comment: Thanks for proofing my suspicion. This actually makes sense. Let me explain: The thing here is that in the inner loop we end up with a scalar variable (``column``) which is just copied when the inner ``ng:repeat`` sets up the scope. On the outer ``ng:repeat`` this is not a problem because the ``row`` is still not a scalar variable but a complex object (array) which will be copied by reference thus the copy is not disconnected from the original.

Comment: @kju , may be i'm tired , but i don't see any mistake here: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/A5X9w/

Comment: This is because your output code has the two indices swapped-around as well. Try to output just ``{{matrix}}``and you will see.

Comment: @JonathanRowny yes , 100% you're right about `row[$index]` ! post it as an answer and i'll be the first for up-vote it ;)

Comment: Well, it was my answer :) I will post it.

Comment: Oh, and I was not fully correct at my comment above. Actually it is not the child scope of the inner ng:repeat which causes the problem but the creation of yet another child scope by the input-tag.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a directive approach which is a little more fun:

```
app.directive("matrix", function($compile){
 return{
 scope:{
   ngModel:'='
 },
 restrict:"E",
 link:function(scope, element, attributes){
   var render = function(){
    var template="";
    scope.ngModel.forEach(function(row, r){
      template+="<p>";
      console.log(scope.ngModel[r]);
      row.forEach(function(column, c){
        template+='<span><input style="width: 20px; text-align: center;" ng-model="ngModel['+r+']['+c+']"></span>';
      });
      template+="</p>";
    });
    element.html(template);
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  }
  render();
  scope.$watch('ngModel', render, true);
 }
}
});
```

which can be used `<matrix ng-model="matrix"></matrix>`

Just because I love directives. Running here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jI7Hi9LKXnDFBd0gXtNZ?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
row[$index]
```

as the `ng:model` in the input tag:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="row[$index]" style="width: 20px; text-align: center;" />
```

The reason why this works and using `column` does not work is this: The `<input>` tag will create a child scope by copying the parent scope. But `column` is a simple/scalar variable. Such a variable will really just be copied. Therefore you end up with a copy in `ng:model` which is not connected to the real variable in your matrix. This is the reason why the AngularJS people stress that you should always have something with a dot inside referenced by `ng-model`.

On the other hand, `row` is still a complex variable (Array) and not a scalar. Such a variable is "copied" by JavaScript not by creating a real copy but by just copying the reference to the data. So you end up with a second reference to the same data. And therefore `row` in the child-scope created by the `<input>` tag is still connected to the original row data in the matrix and two-way data-binding will work.

To stress this again: Never use something without a dot as `ng:model`. AngularJS used to have bad examples doing this on their webpage but it appears that they have mostly/all been changed. But as you can see in this example something `foo[5]` is also ok, because it still references a complex variable. `foo["bar"]` would actually be equal to `foo.bar`.